# not able to get album images from a public album in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to return all images from a public album and getting this error.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'TestAlbumOne' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "Ed/iDn/aAVd"
   }
}
```

Which makes no sense since the album does exist and its set to be public. The documentation is also a bit vague since it doesn't really mention anything about the access token in the request url which I did find after some research. Am I missing something here?

request url:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/TestAlbumOne/photos?access_token={'my access token'}

And thats what I see on the facebook album, which does say its a public album
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the public album of a user account, which is impossible without authorizing that specific user with the `user_photos` permission. Just because stuff is public on facebook.com does not mean you can (or are allowed to) grab it with the API.

Authorize the user with `user_photos` and use the User Token.

About Tokens in general:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

About user authorization:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: "Just because stuff is public on facebook.com does not mean you can (or are allowed to) grab it with the API."....or "Authorize the user with user_photos and use the User Token."....that doesn't mean much to me since it doesn't really tell me how to solve the problem. If you know how to do the latter please share in the post. Thanks

Comment: "Authorize the user with user_photos and use the User Token." is EXACTLY how to solve this. do you expect us to present finished code? that would be your job ;)

Comment: i have added a link to user authorization, if you don´t know about that.